# Any event listener in aws-python once an instance is started

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to start an ec2 instances depends on the state of other ec2 instances through lambda functions.For example, Webserver ec2 instances has to start once Database instances will start.As of now i am using the sleep method of time component but thinking that there should be a way to do my requirement and it's not good for product having a 1-2 minutes of downtime to start just ec2 instances.

```
import boto3
import time
region = 'us-west-1'
db_instances = ['i-12345cb6de4f78g9h', 'i-08ce9b2d7eccf6d26']
web_instances = ['i-12345cb6de4f78h8g', 'i-08ce9b2d7eccf6548']
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=db_instances)
    print('started your instances: ' + str(db_instances))
    time.sleep(60)
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=web_instances)
    print('started your instances: ' + str(web_instances))
```

Suggestions are welcome and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the instance [states](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.state)

   ```
   db_1 = ec2.Instance(id1).state
   db_2 = ec2.Instance(id2).state
   ```
2. Set some flag which becomes True only if both instances are running

   ```
   check_flag = True
   if db_1 == 'running' and db_2 == 'running':
       check_flag = False
   ```
3. Combine both , and add the web startup snippet

   ```
   check_flag = True
   while check_flag:
       db_1 = ec2.Instance(id1).state
       db_2 = ec2.Instance(id2).state
       if db_1 == 'running' and db_2 == 'running':
           check_flag = False
   ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=web_instances)
   ```